# Create a Dynamic Linq to EF Expression to Select IQueryable into new class and assign properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, reflection

I am trying to dynamically create the equivalent of the following Linq.

```
IQueryable<TypeOne> ones;
ones.Select(i => new TypeTwo { TwoProp = i.OneProp });
```

So far I have the following code but it isn't.

```
public class TypeOne
{
    public string OneProp { get; set; }
}

public class TypeTwo
{
    public string TwoProp { get; set; }
}

public static IQueryable<TypeTwo> Tester(IQueryable<TypeOne> data)
{
    ConstructorInfo constructor = typeof(TypeTwo ).GetConstructor(new Type[] { });
    Expression body = Expression.New(constructor);

    ParameterExpression oneParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TypeOne), "one");
    Expression prop1 = Expression.Property(oneParam, "OneProp");

    ParameterExpression twoParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TypeTwo ), "two");
    Expression prop2 = Expression.Property(twoParam, "TwoProp");

    Expression assign = Expression.Assign(prop2, prop1);
    body = Expression.Block(body, assign);

    return data.Select(Expression.Lambda<Func<TypeOne, TypeTwo >>(body, oneParam));
}
```

However I get the following exception-:

Additional information: Expression of type 'System.String' cannot be used for return type 'TypeTwo'

Comment: `public class TwoTwo` - typo?

Comment: yes, thanks for spotting it

Comment: Change it to `Expression.Lambda<Func<TypeOne, string >>(body, oneParam)` - but your expression has other flaws (its not exactly what you're trying to emulate)

Comment: I am trying to convert a list of TypeOne into a list of TypeTwo. Effectively reproducing the linq statement at the top of my question. If I change my Expression.Lambda to use type string, I would be returning a list of string and not a list of TypeTwo. Also it gives the exception Unknown LINQ expression of type 'Block'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [Expression.MemberInit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344570(v=vs.110).aspx) for that, like this:

```
public static IQueryable<TypeTwo> Tester(IQueryable<TypeOne> data)
{
    var source = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TypeOne), "source");
    var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<TypeOne, TypeTwo>>(
        Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(typeof(TypeTwo)),
            Expression.Bind(typeof(TypeTwo).GetProperty("TwoProp"), Expression.Property(source, "OneProp"))),
        source);
    return data.Select(selector);
}
```

You can include as many `Expression.Bind` expressions (i.e. property assignments) as you want.

Comment: Thanks so much, this had me totally stuck!