# How to use expression to assign property in LINQ Select new

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expression

I have the following situation in a generic class:

```
IQueryable<TQuote> query = GetQuotes(ctx)
```

where `ctx` is a database context and `GetQuotes` returns `DbSet<TQuote>`.

Then somewhere down the code the query is executed. Its simplified form is as follows:

```
var list = await query
    .Select(v => new
    {
        v.Id,
        TimeZone = v.Property != null ? (int?)v.Property.TimeZone : null
        // and about 10 more simple properties like v.Id above
    }
    .ToListAsync();
```

where `Property` is a navigation property (to another table) and `TimeZone` is just a regular database column / property of type `int?` in C#.

Everything worked until I tried to use that generic class with the entity, which does not have a navigation property `Property`. So, I would like to replace the "hard coded" expression `v.Property != null ? (int?)v.Property.TimeZone : null` by an abstract member of the class and then override it differently for different `TQuote` types.

I tried something along this signature:

```
protected abstract Expression<Func<TQuote, int?>> GetTimeZone();
```

but then if I use it in LINQ (either directly or assigning to some variable first), then signature of `TimeZone` also changes to `Expression<...>` and if I try to `...Compile().Invoke(v)`, then LINQ complains that LINQ to entities does not support that.

I saw this answer: [Create a Dynamic Linq to EF Expression to Select IQueryable into new class and assign properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33411839/create-a-dynamic-linq-to-ef-expression-to-select-iqueryable-into-new-class-and-a) However, it builds the whole selector by hands and given that I have total of 16 properties that would be a pain on the neck to create and maintain. So, I wonder if I can do something about this `TimeZone` only but leave the rest in a simple LINQ form as above.

Is it possible and if yes, then how exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try nuget LINQKit, https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit.

Below is my attempt.
LinqKit provides the `AsExpandable()` and `Invoke(v)` methods.
I made up properties like `Area.TimeZone` and `Region.RegionalTimeZone`.

```
using LinqKit;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

class QuoteResult
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? TimeZone { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
}

abstract class QuoteHelper<TQuote> where TQuote : Quote
{
    protected abstract Expression<Func<TQuote, int?>> GetTimeZone { get; }

    public IEnumerable<QuoteResult> GetQuoteResults(
        EfExpressionPropertyDbContext ctx)
    {
        IQueryable<TQuote> query = GetQuotes(ctx);
        var getTimeZone = GetTimeZone;

        var list = query
            .AsExpandable()
            .Select(v => new QuoteResult
            {
                Id = v.Id,
                TimeZone = getTimeZone.Invoke(v),
                Note = v.Note
                // and about 10 more simple properties like v.Id above
            })
            .ToList();
        return list;
    }

    public IQueryable<TQuote> GetQuotes(
        EfExpressionPropertyDbContext ctx)
    {
        return ctx.Set<TQuote>();
    }
}

class CommonQuoteHelper : QuoteHelper<CommonQuote>
{
    protected override Expression<Func<CommonQuote, int?>> GetTimeZone
    {
        get { return q => q.Area != null ? (int?)q.Area.TimeZone : null; }
    }
}

class PeculiarQuoteHelper : QuoteHelper<PeculiarQuote>
{
    protected override Expression<Func<PeculiarQuote, int?>> GetTimeZone
    {
        get { return q => q.Region != null ? (int?)q.Region.RegionalTimeZone : null; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for but could not find.